# Trying to use Kentico with powershell

Tags: powershell, kentico

I'm new to using Kentico and I've been given a task to write a script with it using powershell. I'm having a little trouble getting started. I'm following ["PowerShell Calling Reflected Kentico API"](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/three-ways-to-manage-data-in-kentico-using-powershell) to try to get it to work. In particular, I tried:

```
# Configure path to the root of your web project
$webRoot = "C:\inetpub\...\CMS\"

$bin = $webRoot + "bin\"
# Load settings from web.config
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $webRoot + "web.config")
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Configuration
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager].GetField("s_initState", "NonPublic,     Static").SetValue($null, 0)
[Configuration.ConfigurationManager].GetField("s_configSystem", "NonPublic,     Static").SetValue($null, $null)
([Configuration.ConfigurationManager].Assembly.GetTypes() | where     {$_.FullName -eq "System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths"})    [0].GetField("s_current", "NonPublic, Static").SetValue($null, $null)

# Add DLL resolution path
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath($bin);

# Load CMSDependencies
Get-ChildItem -recurse "$webRoot\CMSDependencies\"|Where-Object     {($_.Extension -EQ ".dll")} | ForEach-Object { $AssemblyName=$_.FullName; Try     {Add-Type -Path $AssemblyName} Catch{ "Failed to load assembly: " +     $AssemblyName + " " + $_.Exception.LoaderExceptions}} 

# Load all assemblies from \bin\ (to be sure that all handlers get attached     etc.)
Get-ChildItem -recurse "$bin"|Where-Object {($_.Extension -EQ ".dll")} |     ForEach-Object { $AssemblyName=$_.FullName; Try {Add-Type -Path $AssemblyName}     Catch{ "Failed to load assembly: " + $AssemblyName + " " +     $_.Exception.LoaderExceptions}} 

# Optionally, replace the above with loading only the minimum set of assemblies
#$references = @(("CMS.Base.dll"),("CMS.DataEngine.dll"),    ("CMS.DataProviderSQL.dll"),("CMS.Membership.dll")) | Foreach-Object{ $bin + $_     }
#Add-Type -Path $references

# If the API you are going to use is about to touch the file system set the     web application root path
#[CMS.Base.SystemContext]::WebApplicationPhysicalPath = $webRoot

# Initialize application
"Application initialized:" + [CMS.DataEngine.CMSApplication]::Init();
```

But I'm getting an error on [CMS.DataEngine.CMSApplication]::Init():

```
Exception calling "Init" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user ..."
```

What might be the issue with the login?

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is an error with your SQL connection.  Check your `web.config` file to see if you're using trusted authentication in the connection string (`CMSConectionString`).  If you're using trusted, it may simply be that the user that you're using to run PowerShell does not have the correct SQL permissions.